# Turning off all the anoying password prompts

Tags: 12.04, password

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Its been 2 days that I'm looking for a solution for the enormously annoying password prompts.

The suggestions that i have found, on all of the forums, did not work for me. I actually tried all off them, reinstalled the OS because i could not login any more,....

Now with a new installation, and adjustments to "sudo visudo" (whatever that actually means) I still don't like it.

adjustments that where made:

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL --> root ALL=(ALL:ALL)NOPASSWD:ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL --> %admin ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL --> %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

added line --> `%USER_NAME% ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

Is there anything else I can do to relieve this frustration??